# asp.net c# reflection, creating more instance then expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have a helper method here in class. It returns all the instances of a given interface in all the app domain dlls.

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static List<T> GetOfType<T> ()
  {
    var t =  from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                  from type in asm.GetTypes()
                  where !type.IsInterface && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                  select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   return t.List();
 }
}
```

Edit

Now say i have interface

```
IUserContent
{
  string URL {get;set;}

 }
```

and a implementation say PhotoContent

```
public class PhotoContent
{
     public string URL {get;set]}
}
```

now when i say

```
var c = Helper.GetOfType<IUserContent>();
```

It gives me 9 instances of IUserContent all pointing to photocontent

That is the problem.
I couldnt understand what is the reason.

Can someone help here.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: what instances do you think it is repeating? is there a more concrete example?

Comment: at the moment i have only one concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to get the full name:

```
foreach(var obj in c) {
    Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

that gives you the full type-names (including assemblies) of the types invovled. My *guess* would be that the type has been accidentally declared in multiple assembles or namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `from` clauses in your LINQ query. Could it be that this causes the results to be returned multiple times? I would try using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) instead:

```
var t = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(type => !type.IsInterface && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .Select(type => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

Comment: Possibly, downvoter could not fathom how two from clauses can result in double ups. I certainly can't.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that, Thanks. And I think this could be the answer. Also I would like to add that using Distinct method is another alternative.